# Why is Object Spy not working on Mercury Tours tutorial?

Tags: qtp

I'm using QTP 11.0 on Win 7 Pro SP1. I'm an absolute beginner on QTP.

I'm trying the Mercury Tours tutorial.

When I use Object Spy, any object that is specific to the web page is not recognized. The Object Hierarchy simply shows:

```
Window
  WinObject
```

However, some objects that are specific to the browser are shown. For example, if I hover over the status bar:

```
Window
  WinStatusBar
```

If I click on the status bar:

```
Window: Windows Internet Explorer
  WinStatusBar:msctls_statusbar32
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Have you selected to use the Web Addin when launching QTP? Also make sure the browser is open after QTP and that QTP's extension is enabled (in IE: Tools -> Manager add-ons)

Comment: At QTP launch, Web Addin is the only addin selected (per tutorial instructions). I closed then re-opened IE. Now Object Spy works. In IE add-ins, `BHOManagerClass` was disabled. I enabled it. After all that, Object Spy still OK.

Comment: So did this resolve your problem?

Comment: Sorry - the problem is resolved. I thought the 2 comments might be clear: `Now Object Spy works` and `Object Spy still OK`

Comment: No problem, in that case I'll move my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a short checklist

- Select the Web Addin when launching QTP
- Make sure the browser is open after QTP
- Make sure that QTP's extension (BHOManager) is enabled in IE (Tools -> Manager add-ons)